# Two virtual hosts to one single directory root was created, but I need to pass variable/params from virtualhosts for accessing two different pages

Tags: virtualhost

I created two Virtual Hosts, and targeting to a single web root direcoty.

But I need to access two different profiles with passing of variables from Virtual Hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible using routing technique...

Just we need to get the domain name and check the condition and then route accordingly.